# Windows Media player retrieving additonal info

Tags: mp3, windows-media-player

I have copied a list of MP3 songs to my desktop. and after adding them to a playlist in Windows Media Player, they got additional meta-data information such as the related album, release year etc.

So apperanrtly this data is fetched from some online service that windows/media player is connected to.

**My question is:** What is the name of this service, and is it open for public use so I could also use this API ? - send a name of artist and song and get in return the same information about it to a different application that I develop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMP retrieves its album info from multiple sources, but the most important one is probably [All Music Guide](http://www.allmusic.com/) (AMG). I couldn't find any mention of an API on their website, but you could send them a message to ask.